# getAttribute('value') returns null in Protractor

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor

```
<input type="email" name="email" class="auth0-lock-input" placeholder="yours@example.com" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" value="">
```

In this `input`, I can populate the email `value` using `sendKeys` and I am sure it is because `expect...toEqual` returns `true`.

But then when I try to fetch the value, `getAttribute('value')` returns `null`. I even used `then` function but still nothing. I also tried `getText()` because this `input` is inside a `div` tag but again nothing returns. I searched but I couldn't find any relevant information.

Comment: Can you provide, 1 the "complete html", 2 the code you are using to retrieve / compare the value. Now it is kinda hard to help you with your problem

Comment: Do you actually see the keys being sent to the element visually when you run the test? How do you locate the element?

Comment: @alecxe ...Yes and also when I manually populate the email input I can see in the source code that the 'value' attribute gets populated.

Comment: What if you get the "outerHtml" attribute and print it out to the console? What do you see? Thanks.